# Probability that binary sample mean from population A is larger than sample mean from population B, knowing population mean for A and B

Tags: normal-distribution, binomial-distribution, z-score

My question is as follows. Lake A contains 52% Pikes and 48% other fishes. Lake B contains 47% Pikes and 53% other fishes. You catch 100 fishes from each lake. What is the probability that you will catch more Pikes in lake B than in lake A.

I don't really know how to solve this question and would appreciate some guidance.

My attempts so far is to do a normal approximation to the binomial distribution. Lake A: `N~(0.52, 24.96)` and lake B: `N~(0.47, 24.91).` With this I could calculate the z-score to find out the probability that I for example catch more than 47 pikes from lake B. I guess this method could be used in some way to answer my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A \sim Binom(100, 0.52)$ and $B \sim Binom(100, 0.47)$. If you know that $B = b$, then the probability of catching more Pikes in Lake A can be found with the Normal approximation. *Note: I am ignoring it, but you may want to use the Continuity Correction here.*

$$P(A>B|B=b) = P(A > b) \approx 1 - \Phi\left(\frac{52 - b}{\sqrt{24.96}}  \right)$$

Now, you just use the Law of Total Probability to condition over the different possibilities of $B$.

$$P(A) = \sum_{b=0}^{100}P(A>B|B=b)P(B=b)$$

Where $P(B=b)$ is given by the Binomial PMF, and $P(A>B|B=b)$ can be approximated as above. Alternatively, you can just find $P(A>b)$ numerically with the Binomial distribution.